# Macbook Pro Early 2015 13 inch Retina Cycle count reset

Tags: battery

Apparently, the max cycle count for my MacBook (type is on the title) is 1000. Currently, my cycle count is 990 and I'm wondering if I can reset it without changing my battery? Probably impossible but just in case...

Comment: The only reason I can think of for doing this, is to fool prospective purchasers that the battery is in a better condition than it really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cycle count of MacBooks is logged inside the battery, it is impossible to reset or reduce the count.

The cycle count is a one-way trip. It keeps increasing but can't go back. Just like the TIME.

However, you can replace the battery to bring the cycle count to 0.

You can read more about MacBook Cycle Count [at this blog post](https://www.geekdashboard.com/find-battery-cycle-count-of-macbook/).

[image: How is one charge cycle calculated]

Answer (score 3):

The cycle count of a battery is like an odometer on a car, if you reset it (which you can't do though conventional means), you will have a reading of "zero" but the car will still have all the "mileage" on it.

The cycle count on a battery is just a gauge.  Just because it's at or near 1000 cycles doesn't mean it's going to fail instantly. 1000 cycles is not the max.  It could, conceivably continue to function for many, many more cycles.

It's a good idea to start budgeting for a new battery now knowing that in the near future it will (begin to) fail and you'll need to replace it.